# ggplotly date axis in datetime format instead of date on Ubuntu but not on Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shiny

I wrote a shiny app that contains both ggplot and ggplotly graphs. in the ggplot the date on the x-axis is shown in the correct format `%x`, where in the plotly version the date format on the axis is forced to `%x %T`.

There is also a difference between where I deploy it. on the [shinyapps.io server](http://yonicd.shinyapps.io/CIMDO) the error is corrected but on an [ubuntu instance](http://54.191.51.69/CIMDO/shiny/) I created in AWS the problem persists. The code which I deployed on each site (server&ui) is in [my github repo](https://github.com/yonicd/CIMDO). To switch from ggplot to plotly use the interactive/static radio button.

What is the difference between deploying to shinyapps and an Ubuntu server?